# Matching similar strings in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm using

```
raw:gsub("(%a-):\n".."([%wö  /,.':&%-%%()\n\t]*)",function(a,b) t[a]=b end)
```

to split a string called `raw` by a section header "Something:\n", which is followed by data including the string "Event: " (note the lack of a newline) and store the data in `t["Something"]`.

How can I do this, or should I try to find a workaround?

Comment: Could you please include sample data and explain desired pattern's ending condition? I assume you want to map sections like: `Header A:\n<data><???>Header B:\n<data>`.

Comment: The data's at https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Module:DropTables/rawdata

Comment: Depending on what you are trying achieve, simple `Something:\n<data>`, won't do, as structure is slightly more nested Section (e.g. "Missions") -> Subsection (e.g. "Mercury/Apollodorus (Survival)") -> Rotation -> Drop rate. I assume you want to have this structure parsed into table?

Comment: Exactly. I was, however, going to first separate the headers, then the subheaders, in different steps.

Comment: Also, the data is copied and pasted from another source at https://n8k6e2y6.ssl.hwcdn.net/repos/hnfvc0o3jnfvc873njb03enrf56.html

Comment: I simply couldn't find a way to import it directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for a, b in raw:gsub("%f[^\n%z]([^\n]+):\n", "\0%1\0"):gmatch"%z(%Z+)%z(%Z*)" do
   t[a]=b
end
```

The code finds all "headers" (followed by a colon and a newline) and surrounds them with zero-bytes and than traverses all occurrences with `gmatch`